# Python: I don’t understand why in the result number is more or less

Tags: list, count

My code for count how many times 'x' or 'X' are nearby for '.'

```
def count(list, row, col):
    count = 0
    for row in range((row - 1 if row > 0 else row), (row + 2 if row < (len(list) - 1) else row + 1)):
        for col in range((col - 1 if col > 0 else col), (col + 2 if col < (len(list[0]) - 1) else col + 1)):
            if list[row][col] in ('x', 'X'):
                count += 1
    return count

def calculate_x_count(list):
    for row in range(len(list)):
        for col in range(len(list[0])):
            if list[row][col] == '.':
                list[row][col] = str(count(list, row, col))
    return list
```

My list is:

```
list = [['x', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.'], ['.', 'x', 'x'], ['.', '.', '.']]
```

result should be:

```
[['x', '1', '0'], ['2', '3', '2'], ['1', 'x', 'x'], ['1', '2', '2']]
```

but in the result get:

```
[['x', '1', '0'], ['3', '3', '2'], ['2', 'x', 'x'], ['1', '2', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand how to do, so if somebody is interested:

```
def count(list, row, col):
    count = 0
    for h in range((row - 1 if row > 0 else row), (row + 2 if row < (len(list) - 1) else row + 1)):
        for w in range((col - 1 if col > 0 else col), (col + 2 if col < (len(list[0]) - 1) else col + 1)):
            if list[h][w] == 'x' or list[h][w] == 'X'::
                count += 1
    return count
```